# Selenium: Capture DOM Elements Image

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, javascript

I have an API to capture the image of a particular element in DOM and return them. For that, I have a list of WebElements which needs to be captured into a single webpage. For that same, I have found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13834607/10961238) which works fine if an element is visible on the screen (no need to scroll down to see it).

```
driver.get(urltoconnect);
WebElement ele = getElement();

// Get entire page screenshot
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

// Get the location of element on the page
Point point = ele.getLocation();

// Get width and height of the element
int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight();

// Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth, eleHeight);
ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);

// Copy the element screenshot to disk
File screenshotLocation = new File("C:\\images\\GoogleLogo_screenshot.png");
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation);
```

But the cases where I need to scroll down to see element results in `java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster`. So I have added this.

*What I have tried*

```
//All Results in java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster

//scroll the page until the mentioned element is visible on the current page.
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",element); 

//This will scroll down the page by 450 pixel vertical      
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)");

//AShot
Screenshot fpScreenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(400)).takeScreenshot(driver);
ImageIO.write(fpScreenshot.getImage(),"png",new File("image.png"));
```

---

**Question is** how can I capture the Image of particular elements where some elements need to be scrolled. *Please note that I have multiple elements with there By.id, By.name, By.xpath for multiple sources so I can't set  `fullImg.getSubimage(x,y,w,h)` by `y+100` or something as this might work for one webpage but not for others.* Any Help will be appreciated.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.testing-whiz.com/demoscripts/basic-element.html");
WebElement ele = getElement();

// Get entire page screenshot
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

// Get the location of element on the page
Point point = ele.getLocation();

// Get width and height of the element
int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight();

// Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
try {
BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth, eleHeight);
ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);
}catch (Exception e) {
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)");
    //point.getY() = 732            //From console y = 492.8000183105469 after scroll https://stackoverflow.com/a/38767558/10961238
    //raster.getHeight() = 613
    BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth, eleHeight);
    ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);
}

// Copy the element screenshot to disk
File screenshotLocation = new File("F:\\Images\\1.png");
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation);
```

- Backend: Spring Boot (Java 11)
- Frontend: Angular

Comment: May I know what are you trying to achieve by capturing element's DOM images?

Comment: sure, we have a requirement to capture images and send back to the client. I am able to capture the image when an element is a visible on-screen but for an element which needs to be scrolled to be visible on-screen gives the `java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster`

Answer (score 2):

`WebElement` extends `TakesScreenshot`, which means you can use `getScreenshotAs` on the `WebElement` directly. You can

```
public void takeElementScreenshot(WebElement element) {
    driver.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
    File screenshot = ele.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    //...
}
```

We can [check if the element is in viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244889/5168011) before scrolling, but I don't think it's necessary, just scroll every time